# Opencart payment gateway confirm() and update() syntax

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway, opencart-module

I am trying to develop my first payment gateway in Opencart but I am having issues in processing the order after successful payment or cancelled payment.

This is because I cannot find the syntax of confirm and update functions.

I found this somewhere:

```
$this->model_checkout_order->update(
        $order_id,
        $order_status,
        "",
        true
    );
```

But I just have the order_id variable but I am not sure about the others. Like where do I set them or what should it contain?

Here is my code (callback function):

```
public function callback() {
if (isset($this->request->post['merchant_refID'])) {
  $order_id = $this->request->post['merchant_refID'];
} else {
  die('Illegal Access');
}

$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

if ($order_info) {
  $data = array_merge($this->request->post,$this->request->get);

  //I am using mail function to verify transaction and it is working fine
  if ($data['status'] == '0') {
     mail('a@a.com','success','Success' ,'From: b@b.com');
   }else if ($data['status'] == '-22') {
     mail('a@a.com','failed','amount low' ,'From: b@b.com');
  }else if ($data['status'] == '-202') {
     mail('a@a.com','failed','bank low' ,'From: b@b.com');
  }else if ($data['status'] == '-300') {
     mail('a@a.com','failed','bank high' ,'From: b@b.com');
  }else if ($data['status'] == '-305') {
     mail('a@a.com','failed','failed' ,'From: b@b.com');
  }else if ($data['status'] == '-999') {
     mail('a@a.com','failed','other' ,'From: b@b.com');
  }
}
}
```

How do I update or confirm my order? Is there any guide for this? I am really confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had manage to understand the working and I am posting the same. Please correct me if I am wrong but as far as I've come to know,

The confirm() function must be used to confirm a new order and further process it. For example, if you're placing an order and you've made the payment. Here, you will need to use to confirm() function in order to submit the order and send the email to the buyer. Example of confirm() function:

```
$this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order_id, 2, $message, true);
```

This will mark the $order_id's status to 2 i.e (in my case) Processing. You can check other status code in your database (table : order_status).

On the other hand, the update() function is used to update an order's status (quite not sure about this one). Like you can change the status code of it using :

```
    $this->model_checkout_order->update($order_id, 10, $message, true);
```

Here, it will change the order status to 10 i.e (in my case) Failed. But as far as I know, if you use this for a new order, then it will not send email to a user unlike confirm().

*$message is obviously the message that you wish to add.*

Comment: Could you clarify your answer some? It looks more like notes than an answer to a question. If this answer is already provided by someone else here, I suggest to provide attribution.

Comment: @HunterStevens If you read my question again, I was asking for an example of the update() and confirm() functions. And If you read my answer again, I have explained that only. Also, I figured it out myself that is why I was saying that I'm not sure if I'm completely right and stuff.. Kudos!

Comment: I encountered your answer in a review queue, and commented based on the answer quality alone. Seeing that you asked the Q it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this string before mail function

```
  $this->model_checkout_order->update($order_id, $this->config->get('some-payment_order_status_id'), $comment, false);
```

If you need to send update

> false

change to the

> true

Comment: You answered 50% of my question. I agree with you! Thanks for your answer.